# Migrate content from Joomla to Drupal 8

Tags: joomla, drupal-modules, drupal-8

By obligation of the client, they want to make a new Web in Drupal 8.

Currently they have their website in Joomla (at the moment I do not know the version, they will tell me soon).

With what module can I transfer the information from Joomla to Drupal 8?

Comment: The Joomla version es 2.5.4

Comment: I used the "Joomla to Drupal" module to migrate the contents, but it failed because it did not go to Joomla 2.5

I used the patch discussed here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2262043

And after applying it, I migrated "some" users (not all), and content, only the privacy policy page, the rest did not.

How can I migrate all content correctly?

Comment: I have seen that in Joomla, the contents are created as modules.

And through the pluggin has not migrated any of the 250 modules that the client has high data inside the Joomla.

How can you migrate modules from Joomla to Drupal?

Thank you